# CSS - Rotate border - is it possible?

Tags: html, css

Now I have somethink like this, but it's not very 'responsive' solution. I have idea to rotate border - left or right but I don't know how to do this - is it possible to do this with standard border?

Here is actual solution:

```css
.slant-box .slant-box-content {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
.slant-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cta-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="slant-box">
          <div class="slant-box-content">
            <p class="text-uppercase">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            </p>
            <p>
              tempor incididcillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.slant-box -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.cta-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

**[FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/7eLy1pmL/)**

Comment: What's wrong with using `:before`?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Because I need always to set height and top value on every box on my site + I need so set extra values for responsive code.

Comment: You can set `height: 100%` on your `:before` elements. If that doesn't work, you can use a small snippet of jquery/javascript which sets height of all such `:before` elements according to their containers. Still, if you need to rotate border, you can do so by applying transform skew on your container element e.g. `transform: skewX(10deg);`. As this will also skew the contents of container, you need to have another div inside the container which you can skew back i.e. `transform: skewX(-10deg);`

Comment: check if my solution suits you https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/7eLy1pmL/1/

Comment: Thank you @Vitorinofernandes - paste this to answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example below i have used pseudo element by positioning absolute and added border left with skew so that it adjusts to the parent height

```
.slant-box {
    .slant-box-content {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        padding:15px;
        margin:20px;
    }

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        transform: skewX(-15deg);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/7eLy1pmL/1/